# Creating a "virtual disk" using multiple storage devices

Tags: windows, hard-disk, memory-card

I have a disparate set of storage devices (hard-drives, thumb-drives...) that I would like to use in a specific way. I need a tool to:

1. Combine **several storage devices** and "consolidate" them into a **single emulated storage space** (example : I have three 1Gb USB thumb-drives, I want to see them as a unique 3Gb drive)
2. Manage the pool of storage devices: when I add a new storage device to the storage pool or remove it, the emulated hard-drive will be re-sized (automatically or manually)

Please note that the thumb-drives and hard-disks have different sizes, which means **this is not about RAID**, and they are all "low capacity" drives (the highest one is just a 80 GB hard drive).

I am looking for a solution for Windows 7 or Windows 8 (basically **Windows** Client machines)

Thank you.

Comment: I have been researching and it seems there is nothing that suits your needs (at least in the first 30 or so pages of google search.

Answer (score 1):

You could try creating a *[spanned volume](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc779579(v=ws.10).aspx)*, which is a built-in feature of Windows.

Have a look at the instructions detailed [here](https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/dm_spanned_volume.mspx?mfr=true).

Comment: can that spanned volume arrange that the fast data are in ssd and the slow data are in other drives?