# How to enlarge my SSD storage with help from big hard drive?

Tags: ssd

All this time I store my operating system on SSD and big files in hard disk drive.

Say I want to enlarge my SSD storage. It's like speeding up hard disk but the other way round.

Basically I want windows to see my SSD and hard disk as one drive. The C drive.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating a "virtual disk" using multiple storage devices](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/19237/creating-a-virtual-disk-using-multiple-storage-devices)

Comment: That one doesn't answer my question. Also that seems to be no way to do so.

Comment: [Storage Spaces](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh831739(v=ws.11).aspx), available since Windows 8 and latter, seems like the exact thing you're looking for, and built-in in the OS. Only earlier systems would require external tools.

Answer (score 1):

## ZFS pool

The [ZFS file system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZFS) can pool together multiple physical drives into a single [logical volume](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_volume_management) called [storage pool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZFS#Storage_pools).

[image]
<sub>(source: [wikimedia.org](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/7f/Openzfs.svg/440px-Openzfs.svg.png))</sub>

[OpenZFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenZFS) is a commonly-used open-source implementation of ZFS. [Built into some BSD OSes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZFS#BSD) such as [in TrueOS](https://www.truenas.com/trueos-discontinuation/#zfs-overview) and [in FreeBSD](https://docs.freebsd.org/en/books/handbook/zfs/), [some Linux distros](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZFS#Linux), and elsewhere.

Oracle has their own proprietary fork of ZFS. [Available in Solaris OS products](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZFS#Solaris).

## SAN

> I want windows to see

There seems to be no ZFS implementation for any Microsoft Windows OS, if that is what you meant by “windows” mention. See the Question: [*ZFS Like Alternatives on Windows*](https://serverfault.com/questions/239832/zfs-like-alternatives-on-windows). If this is a deciding factor for you, edit your Question to clarify.

Some answers there suggest you may get a pooling of physical storage similar to ZFS under Windows OS by using a [Storage area Network (SAN)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Storage_area_network).

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it using RAID 0 mode settings in BIOS, but it would basically defeat the advantage of the SSD speed. Detailed description can be found in Wikipedia. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAID
Also I am not sure it would work on live system, so you probably would have to reinstall the Windows.